# Software recommendation: preview file list

Tags: files, software-rec, application

I would need an app showing previews (thumbnails) of a given list of files: is there any?
I know I could simulate it by (soft-)linking the files in a temporary folder, but when the list is huge it's time-consuming.

Just to better explain: when you do a search in your file manager, you get a list of files from different folders BUT in a unified view, and you can preview them (see their thumbnails). Now: I want the exact same view BUT providing the list of the files, without doing a search. Is there an app to do that?

Comment: *"previews of a given list of files*" - what do you mean?

Comment: Thumbnails, like in Nautilus, for example

Comment: So you're talking about image files? Dolphin in KDE can do that, I'm sure other major  file managers can do it as well. https://technastic.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/dolphin-interface.png

Comment: Not just image files. Anyway, I'm talking about a list of files, not a specific folder: the files could be in different locations, but I would like to have them together in one view

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you want/need.

Comment: I think you will have to give an example of the type of behavior that you want to have. It's unclear what you mean by "preview" (and how this differs from just viewing a file).

Comment: Let me edit the question...

Comment: I've never met such GUI apps. Perhaps symlinking is your only solution.